# C++ SImple Looping To Find Largest Number From Array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

Hi I create some mini looping with arrays to find the largest number from array, but the result is a random numbers, here's my code

```
int highest( int num1, int num2, int num3 ){
int bracket[] = {num1, num2, num3};
int result{0};

for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof(bracket); i++)
{
   if ( bracket[i] > result )
   {
       result = bracket[i];
   }
}

return result;
```

}

for example `int highest( 5, 99, 1 )`

the result is `1984875712` but i expected `99`

What's the problem?, Thankyou

Comment: Caution, sizeof(bracket) does not give you the number of elements in bracket.

Comment: Use `std::vector` with `std::vector::size()`.

Comment: @LouisGo: yep, even worse than moving to a fixed-size array...

Comment: Not important, but for just three values, moving to an array is not so useful. A "one liner": `if (n2 > n1) n1= n2; if (n3 > n1) n1= n3; return n1;`

Comment: For real use, you usually want to use [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element). Also note that this code will fail for an array like [-1, -99, -20], showing the largest as 0, even though that isn't in the array.

Comment: `std::cout << sizeof(bracket) << "\n";` -- What does that output?  I bet it isn't 3.  *What's the problem?* -- Also, if you debugged your code using the debugger, you would have seen very easily that the loop executes more than 3 times, thus indicating there is something amiss about using `sizeof(bracket)` in the `for` loop construct.

Comment: Try: `for (std::size_t i = 0; i < std::size(bracket); ++i)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Length of the array is `sizeof(bracket) / sizeof(*bracket)`

Comment: Shall we also dare saying that it is 3 ?

Comment: I have been using this construct million times. There is probably a `lengthof` operator missing...

Comment: Why do we have to use `/ sizeof(*bracket)` ? @w00drow

Comment: In C++ we should prefer `std::size(bracket)`.

Comment: @NicoA.L sizeof returns number of bytes, so it must be divided by sizeof of an element

Answer (score 1):

you could use a vector instead of array.

```
vector <int> bracket{ num1, num2, num3 };
int result = *max_element(bracket.begin(), bracket.end());
```

check about vectors [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

check about max_element [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/)

Answer (score 0):

In C++, it is better to use std::vector or std::array for convenience. The reason is that it is out of bounds, sizeof(bracket) / sizeof(int) is the size of the array